# Salesforce Storage requirements

Tags: data-storage

I have 500,000 Order records and each record size is 100 bytes. could you please tell us how much storage space required in SALESFORCE to store these records. If we try to load these records in ORACLE database typically it takes 52Mb space, how much it will occupy in SALESFORCE?

Answer (score 0):

Each record for a custom object takes up 2kb.

500,000 records will take up 1,000,000kb

---

here is the full list of record sizes for various objects. Note that for the purpose of calculating your data storage it doesn't matter how much data is in a record, the size is always constant.

- Leads -- 2KB
- Contacts -- 2KB
- Accounts -- 2KB
- Person Accounts - 4KB
- Opportunities -- 2KB
- Forecasts -- 2KB
- Events -- 2KB
- Tasks -- 2KB
- Cases -- 2KB
- Case Team Member – 2KB
- Solutions -- 2KB
- Notes -- 2KB
- Custom Reports -- 2KB
- Campaigns - 8KB
- Campaign Members – 1KB
- Contracts – 2KB
- Google Docs – 2KB
- Quotes – 2KB
- Tags: unique tags – 2KB
- Custom Objects – 2KB
- Quote Template Rich Text Data - 2KB
- Articles - 4KB
- Email Message - This is dependent upon the content of the messages, a 100kb email message takes 100kb of data storage space. Text only emails will take less than HTML due to only being the body text and not the html code and text version as well.

NOTE ABOUT PERSON ACCOUNTS
Person Accounts consume a record in both the Account and Contact objects. Each record allocates 2KB, so each Person Account record will require 4KB of storage space.

[What are the various record sizes?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193871&language=en_US)

Comment: Just adding to this, record are not stored by actual size, each object has a set size that is computed agains your total. the size is set regardless of how much or how little data is actually on the record